# How laravel assign this to the model given in resources

Tags: php, laravel, api, class, controller

How Laravel reassigning `$this` to the model given in Api resources and return the just method in the class technically?

Assume we have this:

```
new TeamResource(Team::first());
```

then, in the `TeamResrouce` when we call `$this`, its `Team` model instnace.

and automatically it called `toArray()` method in the `TeamResource` class.

without any constructor in exact class, how?

Comment: where is that `this` ? do you mean `$this` ?

Comment: yeah $this i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toArray()` call as the `toJson()` call on model instances is done in the laravel kernel and request pipeline. here is some code

`Illuminate\Routing\Router` @ `toResponse()`

```php
 public static function toResponse($request, $response)
    {
        if ($response instanceof Responsable) {
            $response = $response->toResponse($request);
        }

        if ($response instanceof PsrResponseInterface) {
            $response = (new HttpFoundationFactory)->createResponse($response);
        } elseif ($response instanceof Model && $response->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $response = new JsonResponse($response, 201);
        } elseif (! $response instanceof SymfonyResponse &&
                   ($response instanceof Arrayable ||
                    $response instanceof Jsonable ||
                    $response instanceof ArrayObject ||
                    $response instanceof JsonSerializable ||
                    is_array($response))) {
            $response = new JsonResponse($response);
        } elseif (! $response instanceof SymfonyResponse) {
            $response = new Response($response);
        }

        if ($response->getStatusCode() === Response::HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) {
            $response->setNotModified();
        }

        return $response->prepare($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Magic method ([`__get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)):

```
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->resource->{$key};
}
```

The API Resource (`Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource`) defines this method so you can access the underlying model's attributes by accessing properties on the resource itself.

```
$this->something === $this->resource->something;
```

> Notice that we can access model properties directly from the `$this` variable. This is because a resource class will automatically proxy property and method access down to the underlying model for convenient access.  [Laravel 5.8 Docs - Eloquent - API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#concept-overview)

Comment: Its okay, but how laravel calls `toArray()` func when make `new TeamResource()` ?

Comment: it doesn't call `toArray` when you make a new instance of `TeamResource`, it is resolved at a later point, most likely as per N69S's answer as `JsonResource` is `JsonSerializable`

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible things, one is I haven't really seen anyone use another class model to initialize a completely different class.  Youre problem may be in that way you initialize.

As well you could try assigning `$this = TeamsResource(Team::first())`